# Yii2 Page link to another with the use of button

Tags: php, yii2

This is my first time using Yii2 so i am confused on how it works. I have this card page in my `views/people/card.php` .However i can only access the page through `web/people/card`. Why?

I am able to link the button in `card.php` to `_card.php` (without changing the url) using controller but how do i link my button in `_card.php` to `_data.php`?

**My controller**

```
 public function actionCard()
 {

  $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
     'query' => People::find(),
  ]);
  $model = '';

    if (Yii::$app->request->post() && isset($_POST['card'])) {
     if(isset($_POST['selection'])){
        $model = People::find()->select('id, name, ic')->where(['id' => $_POST['selection']])->all();
        $content = $this->renderPartial('_card',['model'=>$model]);
        $selection = implode(',', $_POST['selection']);

}
      return $this->render('_design', [
     'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
     'model' => $model,
      ]);

  }
```

Comment: please render partial _card to _data same like card to _card

Comment: @jilesh what do you mean by render?

Answer (score 0):

First You can only access the page through web/people/card. because this is the route managed by yii (is one of the possibile routing way  you can see more [in this guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html)

Second  how do you link button in _card.php to _data.php? (in another controller)
also for this you can do using the routing rules above. In this case you should add the controller name to the route(controller/view) eg:

```
 $content = $this->renderPartial('data/_data',['model'=>$model]);
```

but remember is  not a good practice to use view from different controller.